# CodeIgniter Modifying results of a $query object then return that $query object

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I need to do something like this in a model:

```
function getAll()
{
    $query = $this->db->get('myTable');
    $results = $query->result();

    // Add new property
    foreach ($results as $result)
        $result->newProperty = compileLotsOfStuff($result->column1, $result->column2, ...);

    // Put it back in the $query object
    $query = $result->RECOMPILE_INTO_QUERY();

    // Return the QUERY object, NOT the RESULTS
    return $query
}
```

Is it possible? Can't find anything on google and since tons of controllers use this method everywhere, adding this new property in all the controllers would be tremendous work and code repetition and I cannot use

```
$this->select("*, 'value' AS `newProperty`");
```

in the query as I need the results to calculate it

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean by RECOMPILE_INTO_QUERY(). Do yo mean you want results with newProperty? Your `foreach` loop has no effect.It just adding newProperty to current $result temporary but does not changing $results object.